# Create table from string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using Postgres 8.3.11. I have a table like:

```
user | countries (varchar(100))
  h  | us
  g  | brazil,germany
```

What I would like is the obvious

```
user | countries
  h  | us
  g  | brazil
  g  | germany
```

I created a function that gets a string like 'brazil,germany' and outputs it as a single column table:

```
   |germany|
   |brazil |
```

I can use a cursor to go row by row and execute it to get what I want, but there must be a better SQL-ish way.

Comment: If you already have a function that unnests the list, why not simply join the result to the base table? Btw: it would be a lot easier with a current version of PostgreSQL. 8.3 is to be retired soon!

Comment: every row has a different result, so what do you mean by 'simply join the result'?

Answer (score 1):

[`regexp_split_to_table()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/functions-string.html) (present Postgres in 8.3) should make this easy:

```
SELECT usr, regexp_split_to_table(countries, ',') AS country FROM tbl;
```

Result:

```
 usr | country
-----+---------
 h   | us
 g   | brazil
 g   | germany
```

With short strings this is still the preferable solution in PostgreSQL 9.1.

Performance of `regexp_split_to_table()` degrades with longer strings, though. In 8.4+ use `unnest(string_to_array(...))` instead.

As an aside PostgreSQL 8.3 is getting old. Consider [upgrading to the current version 9.1](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) (9.2 to be released soon).